# Lambda expression in ternary operator

Tags: python, python-3.x, conditional-operator

I am trying to write following code but is throwing error:

```
a = [x if lambda x:  x%2 ==0 else 0 for x in range(10)]
print(a)
```

The error is pointing at lambda statement. Is it illegal to use her? Of yes then why because all my function is returning is the Boolean True or False.

Comment: What is it supposed to do?

Comment: `lambda x: x%2 == 0` is a function. It doesn't make sense here since you aren't calling it (and hence if can't return anything). Are you sure you don't just want: `[x if x % 2 == 0 else 0 for x in range(10)]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aside from `[x if x%2 == 0 else 0 for x in range(10)]` being shorter, you can use a lambda, but you must **call** it.

Either with a default arg (x=x):

```
[x if (lambda x=x: x%2 ==0)() else 0 for x in range(10)]
```

or by explicitely passing x:

```
[x if (lambda x: x%2 ==0)(x) else 0 for x in range(10)]
```

Result for either case:

```
[0, 0, 2, 0, 4, 0, 6, 0, 8, 0]
```

Comment: Th problem here is that it unnecessarily defines a `lambda` function for each iteration of the `for` loop.

Comment: I'm not saying anyone *should* do this, but if you really really really want to use a lambda (e.g. educational purposes), this is how it can be done.

Comment: Oh, I get it! Same goes for my answer :)

Comment: I don't see what educational value there is in misusing a lambda in this way.

Comment: Just playing around with lambdas and comprehension. I was wondering if I could use both at a time. But thanks to Mike, he gave answer to all my questions!

Answer (score 1):

In order to utilize your `lambda` function within your list comprehension, simply define a variable to store the function:

```
func = lambda x: x % 2 == 0

a = [x if func(x) else 0 for x in range(10)]
print(a)
```

Output:

```
[0, 0, 2, 0, 4, 0, 6, 0, 8, 0]
```

Comment: [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations) specifically recommends against this. `Always use a def statement instead of an assignment statement that binds a lambda expression directly to an identifier`

Answer (score 0):

`lambda x:  x%2 ==0`  is a function, not a condition.

Why not use this instead?

```py
a = [x if x%2 == 0 else 0 for x in range(10)]
print(a)
```

Comment: Actually I purposely wanted to use lambda here. I thought since, the if condition should evaluate to either True or False so why not put a function here which returns true or false based on some condition? At last my function is returning a Boolean value which is a condition should evaluate to.

Comment: In that case, my answer is indeed not sufficient. However, you are literally passing the function itself. You should also call the lambda function. Mike Scotty has given a good answer on this!